# "Non-critical" zeros of $\zeta$ and the $\zeta$-cycles of Connes and Consani

Tags: nt.number-theory, sp.spectral-theory, riemann-zeta-function, noncommutative-geometry

In the recent preprint of Connes and Consani https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.01715 a new spectral realization of the critical zeros of $\zeta$ (edit: defined as being those on the critical line only, see the comments) is presented.

Compared to Connes' older paper which gave the first one https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s000290050042, there are several differences, in particular in the function spaces used.

In the new work, the critical zeros of $\zeta$ are related to the non-denseness of a certain space in a parametric family $L^2(C)$, and the values of C for which this happens are termed $\zeta$-cycles (edit: see definition 6.1. page 51) .

In the 1999 paper, it was said that, beyond the critical zeroes appearing as a spectrum, the other zeroes of $\zeta$ appeared as resonances (in particular those in the critical strip, if any).

All this is mostly over my head, but I'd like to ask :

> is the characterization of points in the spectrum of an operator as places where some space is not dense in another space something new? And could that be extended to resonances?

Comment: The phrase 'critical zeros' is non standard, more traditionally one would refer to 'non-trivial zeros' for those in the critical strip.  Are you reading critical zeros as being on the critical line?  Otherwise your parenthetical comment "(in particular those in the critical strip, if any)" makes no sense to me.

Comment: Yes, that's the terminology from the paper, if I understood well : critical zeros are those on the critical line, not strip.

Comment: I'm looking at the arXiv paper, and it doesn't explicitly say that.  And I don't see a clear reason to assume that meaning.  You might want to write to the authors and verify/clarify.

Comment: Thanks for looking. I still think it does, in the introductory section on page 49 they say theorem 6.4 associates a family of Hilbert spaces to critical zeros of $\zeta$ and in that theorem page 52 they explicitly mention zeroes on the critical line.

Comment: The paper of Connes and Consani refer explicitly to zeros on the critical line. For example see Theorem 6.4 on page 52. The book by H. Iwaniec Lectures on the Riemann zeta function, have a Part with title  The critical zeros After Levinson, and uses critical zeros to denote zeros on the critical line.

Comment: Yes, it's clear that they use "critical zero" to mean "zero on the critical line".  They are not proving the Riemann Hypothesis using the Hilbert-Polya approach (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93P%C3%B3lya_conjecture).  It looks like they are "merely" finding a natural self-adjoint operator whose eigenvalues determine the zeros of the Riemann zeta function on the critical line Re(z) = 1/2.